# Python Dataframes: How can I apply a function to value x and y, where x is in df1 and y is in df2?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling to find a nice solution to this problem:

I have a 100-rows-dataframe `df1`

```
, Col 0, Col 1, Col 2, Score, Combined
...
23 Oslo, isCapitalOf, Norway, 0.9, None
...
```

I also have another 100-rows-dataframe `df2`

```
, Col 0, Col 1, Col 2, Score, Combined
...
43 Norway, highestMountain, Galdhøpiggen, 0.7, None
...
```

The aim is to update the score value in `df2` by
applying a function (for instance multiplication), between the score values in the `df1` and `df2`, where the column value in `df1` `col2` equals the column value `df2` `col 0`, which is Norway in the example.

```
, Col 0, Col 1, Col 2, Score, Combined
...
43 Norway, highestMountain, Galdhøpiggen, 0.7, 0.63
...
```

Then, do this for all mappings between these columns, not just "Norway". Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you interested only in matches between `Col 2` in `df2` and `Col 0` in `df1` or in all possible combinations of columns?

Comment: The first you mentioned :) Col 2 in df1 to Col0 to df 2. Also, It would be nice to generalize the function used. In the example, I specified multiplication. However, if it can be generalized to function f (which could be multiplication or the minimum etc), that would be awesome!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full working solution to use with any custom function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data1 = {'Col 0': ['Oslo', 'Paris'],
         'Col 1': ['isCapitalOf', 'isCapitalOf'],
         'Col 2': ['Norway', 'France'],
         'Score': [0.9, 0.8]}

data2 = {'Col 0': ['Norway', 'France'],
         'Col 1': ['highestMountain', 'highestMountain'],
         'Col 2': ['Galdhøpiggen', 'Mont Blanc'],
         'Score': [0.7, 0.6]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


def apply_function_on_mapped_scores(df1, df2, func):
    # Create a mapping from df1 Col 2 values to Score values
    mapping = df1.set_index('Col 2')['Score']

    # Apply the function on the mapped score values
    df2['Combined'] = df2.apply(lambda x: func(x['Score'], mapping.get(x['Col 0'], 1)), axis=1)

    return df2


# Test the function with multiplication
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

df2_with_multiply = apply_function_on_mapped_scores(df1, df2, multiply)
print("Dataframe with multiplied scores:")
print(df2_with_multiply)


# Test the function with minimum
def minimum(x, y):
    return np.minimum(x, y)

df2_with_minimum = apply_function_on_mapped_scores(df1, df2, minimum)
print("Dataframe with minimum scores:")
print(df2_with_minimum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) between columns for countries with exact match, so removed digits and space in `df2['Col 0']` and then multiple by `df2['Score']` with [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df2['Combined'] = df2['Col 0'].map(df1.set_index('Col 2')['Score']).mul(df2['Score'])
print (df2)
       Col 0            Col 1         Col 2  Score  Combined
43 Norway  highestMountain  Galdhøpiggen    0.7      0.63
```

General solution working per Series:

```
#function working with arrays
def func(a,b):
    return a * b

df2['Combined'] = func(df2['Col 0'].map(df1.set_index('Col 2')['Score']), df2['Score'])

print (df2)
    Col 0            Col 1         Col 2  Score  Combined
0  Norway  highestMountain  Galdhøpiggen    0.7      0.63
```

---

```
def func(a,b):
    return np.minimum(a,b)

df2['Combined'] = func(df2['Col 0'].map(df1.set_index('Col 2')['Score']), df2['Score'])

print (df2)
    Col 0            Col 1         Col 2  Score  Combined
0  Norway  highestMountain  Galdhøpiggen    0.7       0.7
```

Comment: I guess the digits you are removing is just the index, or @Zimenez?

Comment: Correct. The first number is just the row_id, and not important. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the suggestion! I am looking into this.

Comment: @jezrael, is it difficult to generalize the multiplication to a function with the two scores as input values? Such that it can be multiplication, min, max, and other t-norms? Sorry I have should have mentioned this in the original post.

Comment: @Zimenez - You are welcome. Do you need fast solution?

Comment: @jezrael, No need; this works just fine! But thanks for the offer!